# Google remarketing/conversion currency code errors

Tags: tracking

I am implementing a simple **Google remarketing/conversion script** to a client site... But having issues with the setting of the currency code for some reason.

I get **2 errors** using the tag assistant which are:

1. > Conversion Value should be prefixed with standard currency.
2. > Non-standard implementation

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = ABC123;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "ABC123";
var google_remarketing_only = false;
var google_conversion_value = 1.00;
var google_conversion_currency = "GBP";
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" 
src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/ABC123/?value=1&amp;currency_code=GBP&amp;label=ABC123&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
```

Anyone know what the issue is? Google help online seems to skip this issue!

Comment: Please enter full error messages as they are shown and format them properly.

Comment: Hi @MaciejJureczko - Those are the error messages I get in the Tag Assistant.

Comment: Anyone any ideas on what the code issue is here?